# PHP include not working for nav bar

Tags: php, html

I am writing a nav bar that I want to include across all web pages. I have it written and my home page written, but the include is not importing the nav.html for some reason. My homepage is index.php and the nav is header.html The files are in the same xampp directory and apache is running.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>World Congress CS-IT Conferences</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id = "wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>World Congress CS-IT Conferences</h1>
        <h4>"The question of whether a computer can think is no more interesting than the question of whether a submarine can swim."- Edsger W. Dijkstra</h4>
    </header>
        <hr>
</div>

<?php include('header.html');?>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#general").mouseover(function(){
            $('#dropdown').css("display", "block");
        });
        $("#general").mouseout(function(){
            $('#dropdown').css("display", "none");
        })
        $("#dropdown").mouseover(function(){
            $('#dropdown').css("display", "block");
        });
        $("#dropdown").mouseout(function(){
            $('#dropdown').css("display", "none");
        })

    })
</script>

<script>
    function underConstruction(){
        alert("This page is under constructon, check back soon!");
    }
</script>

<img alt = "Join Us From July 6, 2017 - July 11, 2017" id = "banner" src = "banner.jpg"/>
<br>
<br>
<body>
    <p id = "welcome">Welcome to the World Congress CS-IT Conferences online portal. To navigate our site, please follow the links to the left of the page to learn more information regarding submitting papers, panels, the full conference progam, and much more. Register and login to access members only pages.</p><br>

    <div id = "featured">OUR FEATURED KEYNOTE</div>


<img alt = "Elon Musk" id = "speaker" src = "musk.jpg"/>
<p id = "founder">Elon Musk, CEO and CTO of SpaceX</p>

</body>

<footer>
        <p id = "copyright">&copy;2016 Kevin Handeli All Right Reserved.</p>

</footer>

<html>



<nav>
    <p>Explore Our Site</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "keynote.html">Keynote Speakers</a></li>
        <li id = "general"><a>General Information &#9655;</a></li>
        <li><a href = "callforpapers.html">Call For Paper</a></li>
        <li><a href = "importantdates.html">Important Dates</a></li>
        <li><a href = "majorareas.html">Major Areas</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" onclick = "underConstruction()">Paper Submission</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" onclick = "underConstruction()">Reviewer Login</a></li>
        <li><a href = "registration.html">Online Registration</a></li>
        <li><a href = "program.html">Conference Program</a></li>
        <li><a href= "authorsguide.html">Guidelines</a></li>
        <li><a href = "comments.html">Comments and Feedback</a></li>
        <div class = "dropdown-menu" id = "dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href = "fee.html">Conference Fee</a></li>
                <li><a href = "location.html">Hotel Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: It is not nav.html, that was a typo when i was naming files.

Comment: `require();` would give you 'better' errors

Comment: Try changing the name of file **header.html** to **header.php**. Now include it using `require_once("header.php")`. That should do it